# Append to typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Is it possible to append some HTML to the end of a typeahead? I've tried many different things but none have worked.

What I'm trying to do is have the last result of the typeahead be `Search for "< what the user typed into the input >"`.

Here's what I've tried on JSFiddle: [**http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8621/**](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/8621/)

What I expected it to do was append the `<li>` at the end of the dropdown once it's created, but it doesn't. Why?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-source="[&quot;Alabama&quot;,&quot;Alaska&quot;,&quot;Arizona&quot;,&quot;Arkansas&quot;,&quot;California&quot;,&quot;Colorado&quot;,&quot;Connecticut&quot;,&quot;Delaware&quot;,&quot;Florida&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Hawaii&quot;,&quot;Idaho&quot;,&quot;Illinois&quot;,&quot;Indiana&quot;,&quot;Iowa&quot;,&quot;Kansas&quot;,&quot;Kentucky&quot;,&quot;Louisiana&quot;,&quot;Maine&quot;,&quot;Maryland&quot;,&quot;Massachusetts&quot;,&quot;Michigan&quot;,&quot;Minnesota&quot;,&quot;Mississippi&quot;,&quot;Missouri&quot;,&quot;Montana&quot;,&quot;Nebraska&quot;,&quot;Nevada&quot;,&quot;New Hampshire&quot;,&quot;New Jersey&quot;,&quot;New Mexico&quot;,&quot;New York&quot;,&quot;North Dakota&quot;,&quot;North Carolina&quot;,&quot;Ohio&quot;,&quot;Oklahoma&quot;,&quot;Oregon&quot;,&quot;Pennsylvania&quot;,&quot;Rhode Island&quot;,&quot;South Carolina&quot;,&quot;South Dakota&quot;,&quot;Tennessee&quot;,&quot;Texas&quot;,&quot;Utah&quot;,&quot;Vermont&quot;,&quot;Virginia&quot;,&quot;Washington&quot;,&quot;West Virginia&quot;,&quot;Wisconsin&quot;,&quot;Wyoming&quot;]" data-items="10" data-provide="typeahead" style="margin: 0 auto;" class="span3">
```

jQuery:

```
$(".typeahead.dropdown-menu").append('<li data-value="Custom" class=""><a href="#">CUSTOM TEXT</a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menu is built during the typeahead filtering process. If you inspect it "on load", you will notice it is empty.

Depending on your specific problem you're trying to solve, i can think of two possible solutions.

One solution would be to extend the typeahead plugin and provide a custom "render" function. This would allow you to modify the list rendering process and append additional `<li>`s as well as anything else you like. This is probably regarded as the "best way".

Another more hacky solution would be to place your custom value in the data source, then provide a custom "matcher" function which runs the original matcher along with an additional clause for your custom value.

Of course solutions are tied to problems and without really knowing the very specifics of what you want to do, i can't recommend which one to use. But those are your two options as far as i can think.